# Unable to install react-native sub-specs to my iOS application

Tags: swift, react-native

I have followed the below steps to integrate React into my iOS app,
https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps#2-install-javascript-dependencies

but after settings up the react and react-native version setup in the package.json file, then I added pod specs to my iOS pod file, and then I am running pod install.

pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
'Core',
'CxxBridge',
'DevSupport',
'RCTText',
'RCTNetwork',
'RCTWebSocket',

## Add any other subspecs you require

]

*Getting this error: *
No podspec found for React in ../node_modules/react-native

Note: node_modules path is the correct place.

I am trying to integrate react into my native iOS app So that I can continue development in react native.